# Special function in glut error message

Tags: c++

Not sure how to fix this error?

Here is the message...

```
 error C2664: 'glutSpecialFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(unsigned char,int,int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int,int,int)'   
 1>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

And here is my code....

The function is called in the main.

```
    glutSpecialFunc(Keyboard);
```

Here is the method.

```
void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

if (key == 27) {
    exit(0);
} else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {
    drawing = 1;
} else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {
    drawing = 2; 
} else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {
    drawing = 3;
} else if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {
    drawing = 4;
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`glutSpecialFunc(Keyboard);` is expecting functions that only include int's as parameters.

So you just need to change your function declaration like this:

```
  void Keyboard(int key, int x, int y) {

    if (key == 27) {
        exit(0);
    } else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {
        drawing = 1;
    } else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {
        drawing = 2; 
    } else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {
        drawing = 3;
    } else if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {
        drawing = 4;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
  }
```

From openGL documentation:

> **glutSpecialFunc**
>
> *glutSpecialFunc* sets the special keyboard callback for the current
>   window.
>
> **Usage**
>
> void glutSpecialFunc(void (*func)(int key, int x, int y));

Comment: error C2664: 'glutSpecialFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(unsigned char,int,int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int,int,int)'

Comment: @user2864187: Mark this answer as accepted in that case :P Your reputation will go up and so will the author's. Also, the better way to show thanks is to up-vote the answer, that is how Stack Overflow is designed to work. In any event, try not to think of keyboards as being limited to the ASCII character set - there are plenty of keys on even U.S. keyboards that do not belong to printing character sets, thus it is rarely the case that a key identifier will be `char`. `int` is pretty common for these callbacks, sometimes there is even another `int` with a bitmask for modifier keys.